# On chaining and lettable operators

Tags: rxjs5, rxjs-lettable-operators

I am undecided if this is the right place to ask this question, or StackOverflow might be best for this. So here i go.

My introductions to rxjs was through the excellent [Angular](https://angular.io) framework and throughout every tutorial and in practice has been "import whatever you need from `add/operator` and then chain it. eg.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { empty } from 'rxjs/observable/empty';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
// Other rxjs import
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

Class SomeClass {
  @Effect
  search$ = this._action
    .ofType<search.SearchCountry>(search.SEARCH_COUNTRY)
    .map(action => {
      return action.payload;
    })
    .switchMap(query => {
      if (query === '') {
        return empty();
      }
      const nextSearch$ = this._action.ofType(search.SEARCH_COUNTRY).skip(1);

      return this._searchService
        .search(query)
        .do(query => console.log(query))
        .takeUntil(nextSearch$)
        .map((result: RestResponseInterface) => {
          return new search.SearchCountryComplete(result);
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return Observable.of(new search.SearchError('Undocumented API Error'));
    });
}
```

As [explained](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md#usage) in lettable documentaion, and If I am reading this right, chaining is discouraged as way forward, and pipe is the recommended implementation. The same implementation should be written as follows

```
import { tap, take, takeUntil, skip, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'; // Import statements have changed

search$ = this._action
    .pipe(
        ofType<search.SearchCountry>(search.SEARCH_COUNTRY),
        map(action => action.payload),
        switchMap(query => {
            if (query === '') {
                return empty();
            }

            const nextSearch$ = this._action.ofType(search.SEARCH_COUNTRY).skip(1);

            return this._searchService
                .search(query)
                .pipe(tap(qyery => console.log(query)), takeUntil(nextSearch$), map((result: RestResponseInterface) => new search.SearchCountryComplete(result)));
        })
    )
    .catch(error => {
        return Observable.of(new search.SearchError('Undocumented API Error'));
    });
```

Because when i read the source,  especially after https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Rx.ts#L41 its seems that chaining is perfectly acceptable, however, there is a proposal https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2913, which is discussing adding `rxjs/add/*` as a seperate package.

My question is, how will this effect chaining in future?

Comment: it's also mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3212) - which suggests the patching imports would change to something like `import from 'rxjs-deprecations/add/operator/foo';`

Comment: @cartant but how does this effect chaining .. in the future upgrades?

Comment: Chaining itself wouldn't be affected. In the current version, the chaining operators are trivial wrappers around the lettable operators. The only change would be to the import statements, as the chaining wrappers would be moved elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though RxJS v6 is focusing completely on lettable operators (and actually dropping support for chainable operators). All evidence points towards they having a proper migration guide and support ([eg: the RxJS 5 - 6 migration guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12nlLt71VLKb-z3YaSGzUfx6mJbc34nsMXtByPUN35cg/preview)) but it seems as though the days of chainable operators are numbered, even if there is short-term support for a while.